# select *from table1 where id='"+comboBox1.Text+"'and name='"+comboBox2.Text+"'

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to execute this command

```
select * from table1 where id='"+comboBox1.Text+"'and name='"+comboBox2.Text+"'
```

but I don't want them to be considered if they were empty, for example if `combobox1.Text` is empty, I want the command to be like

```
select * from table1 where name='"+comboBox2.Text+"'
```

Comment: You should look into SQL injections ... Please use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a check with the text boxes like

```
if (comboBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0) {
    // your query 
}
else{
 // other query
 }
```

***But you should be using parameterised queries. Building up your queries like that leaves you open to SQL injection.***

So your SQL String should be

```
select * from table1 where id=@id and name=@name
```

And you add the parameters to the command object before executing the query.

Comment: i don't see how i can use the parameterised query ? if (comboBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0) {
 //what should i do in this case ??
}
else{
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "id");
 }  ,thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can build up your query as you go, and still protect yourself from SQL injection:

*(I'm writing this from memory, it should compile...)*

```
 using (var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
 {
     var sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE");

     using (var cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = conn })
     {
         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))
         {
             sb.Append(" id = @ID");
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(comboBox1.Text));
         }

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text))
         {
             sb.Append(" name = @NAME");
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", comboBox2.Text);
         }

         var query = sb.ToString();

         cmd.CommandText = query.EndsWith("WHERE") ? query.Remove(query.Length - 5) : query;

         conn.Open();

         using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 // do whatever you need to do with your data
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Something to keep in mind...

This could get out of hand if you have a dozen `if` blocks instead of just two, and then start nesting more `if` blocks inside of those. Maintenance will become a nightmare.

It may just be easier, if you only have a few conditions, to just create a few separate queries and determine which one is called instead of building a query dynamically like this.

Comment: String.IsNullOrEmpty will not check the space?

Comment: so if all combobox were empty the query will be "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE" ? ,though your solution is a good idea ,and thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution i want

MySqlDataAdapter cmd = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from table1 where   (ID=@id or @id2) and (name=@name or @name2)  ", co);

```
        if (comboBox1.Text == "")
        {
            cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "1");
            cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id2", "1");
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", comboBox1.Text);
            cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id2", "0");
        }

        if (comboBox2.Text == "")
        {
            cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "1");
            cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name2", "1");
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", comboBox1.Text);
            cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name2", "0");
        }
```

//thanks everyone for the help , i used all what u gave me to create this solution